# Can a method (prototype) of a user defined javascript object use the document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, oop, dom

I'm trying to learn about user-defined objects in JavaScript. Specifically, I'm trying to create a method of a user-defined object that will use the `document.getElementById("holder")` and append to it using `document.createElement('p')` and append to it a text node with `document.createTextNode("text")`.

Currently, my method is not doing that. I've tested the method and it is getting called, but nothing appears in the page from the `item.appendChild(otheritem)`. I've looked through other posts but none explained my situation, at least that I am aware of. My code is below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Person(fn, ln) {
                this.fname = fn;
                this.lname = ln;
            }
            Person.prototype.getFullName = function () {
                var myPara = document.createElement('p');
                var strFullName = document.createTextNode("super");
                myPara.appendChild(strFullName);
                var objHolder = document.getElementById("objHolder");
                objHolder.appendChild(myPara);
            };

            function getSome() {
                var fN = document.getElementById("fname").value;
                var lN = document.getElementById("lname").value;
                var Myperson = new Person(fN, lN);
                alert(Myperson.fname);
                Myperson.getFullName();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="holder">First Name:
            <input id="fname" type="text" width="40" />Last Name:
            <input id="lname" type="text" width="40" />
            <button id="buildObj" value="Click" onClick="getSome()">Click</button>
        </form>
        <div id="objHolder"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help or recommendations would be appreciated. Also, if I'm missing a key concept, knowing that would be good too.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Why it is named getFullName when it doesn't return anything and have side-effects? you should rename it to something appropriate e.g. createNameElem

Comment: To answer your title question: Yes, of course it can. Why shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The append works but at the same time the form is submitted, so it redirects to another page. You need to cancel the natural browser behaviour of submitting the form via `return false` in an event handler for the `submit` event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Person(fn,ln) {
this.fname = fn;
this.lname = ln;
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function()
{

var myPara = document.createElement('p');
var strFullName = document.createTextNode("super");myPara.appendChild(strFullName);
var objHolder = document.getElementById("objHolder");objHolder.appendChild(myPara);
};

function getSome(){
var fN = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lN = document.getElementById("lname").value;

var Myperson = new Person(fN,lN);
alert(Myperson.fname);
Myperson.getFullName();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="holder">
First Name: <input id="fname" type="text" width="40" />
Last Name: <input id="lname" type="text" width="40" />
<button id="buildObj" value="Click" onClick="getSome()">Click</button>
</form>
<div id="objHolder">
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('holder').onsubmit=function(){ return false; }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The more elegant method is to use the `event` object and then call `event.preventDefault` but due to browser inconsistencies it takes a lot of code to get it right.. so for this basic example, `onsubmit` and `return false` should suffice.

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for. I didn't realize that it was trying to go to another page. I still have lots of learning to do. Thanks again!